# Confusion about epochs in validation/test

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

This is specific to neural networks.
I see a lot of posts with epoch vs loss graphs for validation sets.
I am a bit confused about that.

For the validation set, shouldn't there be only one epoch? Because all weights and biases have been calculated during the testing phase. And there won't be any backward propagation, just one forward pass to test how well the model does on the validation set.

Comment: After each epoch of training, you compute validation metrics on the validation set. (Of course, you could compute them as often as you want, e.g. after every 500 training examples, but this is a good starting point for thinking about your question.)

Comment: So are the weights from the training used on the validation set?

Comment: Yes. Every time you validate your model, you use the current weights of the model.

Comment: For your schema, yes, estimate training error, validation error, and test error during each epoch, plot the error lines as a function of epoch (or "sweep" through the data)

Answer (score 0):

Validation can happen after training or they can be complementary. When it happens after the training is completed, the validation data passes through the neural network (which has fixed weights and biases) in one epoch. Complementary training and validation means the following. In one epoch training is done and right after it validation is done; next epoch, training is done again and again validation happens. Each time weights and biases are updated, there is an estimation of the neural network's performance. So we have the same number of epochs for training and validation. When you design your model, you can go for either single validation after complete training or complementary training and validation.